# OpenMP SIMD on Power8

Tags: openmp, vectorization, simd, powerpc

I'm wondering whether there is any compiler (`gcc`, `xlc`, etc.) on Power8 that supports OpenMP SIMD constructs on Power8? I tried with XL (13.1) but I couldn't compile successfully. Probably it doesn't support simd construct yet.

I could compile with gcc 4.9.1 (with these flags `-fopenmp -fopenmp-simd` and `-O1`). I put differences between 2 asm files.

Can I say that gcc 4.9 is able to generate altivec code? In order to optimize more, what am I supposed to do? (I tried with `-O3`, restrict treatment)

My code is very simple:

```
int *x, *y, *z;
x = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
y = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
z = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));   

#pragma omp simd
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  z[i] = a * x[i] + y[i];
```

And generated assembly is here

```
  .L7:
  lwz 9,124(31)
  extsw 9,9 
  std 9,104(31)
  lfd 0,104(31)
  stfd 0,104(31)
  ld 8,104(31)
  sldi 9,8,2
  ld 10,152(31)
  add 9,10,9
  lwz 10,124(31)
  extsw 10,10
  std 10,104(31)
  lfd 0,104(31)
  stfd 0,104(31)
  ld 7,104(31)
  sldi 10,7,2
  ld 8,136(31)
  add 10,8,10
  lwz 10,0(10)
  extsw 10,10
  lwz 8,132(31)
  mullw 10,8,10
  extsw 8,10
  lwz 10,124(31)
  extsw 10,10
  std 10,104(31)
  lfd 0,104(31)
  stfd 0,104(31)
  ld 7,104(31)
  sldi 10,7,2
  ld 7,144(31)
  add 10,7,10
  lwz 10,0(10)
  extsw 10,10
  add 10,8,10
  extsw 10,10
  stw 10,0(9)
  lwz 9,124(31)
  addi 9,9,1
  stw 9,124(31)
```

GCC with `-O1 -fopenmp-simd`

```
.L7:
lwz 9,108(31)
mtvsrwa 0,9
mfvsrd 8,0
sldi 9,8,2
ld 10,136(31)
add 9,10,9
lwz 10,108(31)
mtvsrwa 0,10
mfvsrd 7,0
sldi 10,7,2
ld 8,120(31)
add 10,8,10
lwz 10,0(10)
extsw 10,10
lwz 8,116(31)
mullw 10,8,10
extsw 8,10
lwz 10,108(31)
mtvsrwa 0,10
mfvsrd 7,0
sldi 10,7,2
ld 7,128(31)
add 10,7,10
lwz 10,0(10)
extsw 10,10
add 10,8,10
extsw 10,10
stw 10,0(9)
lwz 9,108(31)
addi 9,9,1
stw 9,108(31)
```

In order to clarify and understand details, I have one more application which is n^2 nbody application. This time my question is related with these compilers (gcc 4.9 and XL 13.1 ) and architectures (Intel and Power).

I put all the codes into gist https://gist.github.com/grypp/8b9f0f0f98af78f4223e#file-input-c
( *full version of input code input.c* )

1. **Power8 & XLC** - It says "was not SIMD vectorized because it contains function calls. (there is sqrtf)". It's reasonable. But in the asm code I can see xsnmsubmdp is it normal? *(the assembly: https://gist.github.com/grypp/8b9f0f0f98af78f4223e#file-power8-xlc-noinnersimd-asm)*
2. **Power8 & gcc** I tried to compile it in 2 ways (with omp simd construct and without). It changed my asm code, is it normal? (According to OpenMP, the code should not contain function call) *(Assembilies: https://gist.github.com/grypp/8b9f0f0f98af78f4223e#file-power8-gcc-noinnersimd-asm & https://gist.github.com/grypp/8b9f0f0f98af78f4223e#file-power8-gcc-innersimd-asm)*
3. **i74820K & gcc** I did a same test with omp simd and without it. The output codes are different as well. Does FMA effect this code block ? *(Assembilies: https://gist.github.com/grypp/8b9f0f0f98af78f4223e#file-i74820k-gcc-noinnersimd-asm & https://gist.github.com/grypp/8b9f0f0f98af78f4223e#file-i74820k-gcc-innersimd-asm)*

Thanks in advance

Comment: The OpenMP `simd` construct is part of OpenMP 4.0 and as such is supported by GCC 4.9 and later. XL C 13.1.0 provides partial support.

Comment: @HristoIliev thank you for quick reply. I put more details into question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand Power's ISA. Make sure to hint the compiler that `x`, `y`, and `z` cannot alias each other. Otherwise the compiler might be reluctant to vectorise the code. You could either give the pointers the `restrict` treatment or apply some compiler-specific pragma that hints the compiler that the pointers dereferenced inside the loop cannot alias each other. You might also have to hint the compiler that the memory allocation is quad-word aligned.

Comment: You have probably compiled with `-O3` that enables the tree vectoriser of GCC even without the OpenMP SIMD pragmas - both x86 assembly outputs are fully vectorised. AVX has the `VRSQRTPS` instruction that computes 1/sqrt(x) of 8 single-precision numbers simultaneously while Power8 lacks such instruction (it even lacks vectorised square root).

Comment: @HristoIliev I compiled with -O3 yes, I thought same thing with AVX. But why XL compiler couldn't vectorize i didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XL compiler on POWER Linux currently only supports a subset of the OpenMP 4.0 features.  The SIMD construct feature is not supported at the moment, so the compiler will not recognize the construct in your source code.

However, if vectorization is what you're looking for then the good news is that the XL compiler should already automatically vectorize your code as long as you use at least the following optimization options

> -O3 -qhot -qarch=pwr8 -qtune=pwr8

These options will enable [high-order loop transformations](http://vaidbld.canlab.ibm.com:10301/help/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp1311.belinux.doc/compiler_ref/opt_hot.html?resultof=%22%2D%71%68%6F%74%22%20%22%71%68%6F%74%22%20) along with POWER8 specific optimizations, including loop auto-vectorization for your loop.

Afterwards, you should see some VMX & VSX instructions in the generated assembly code similar to the following:

```
 188:   19 2e 80 7c     lxvw4x  vs36,0,r5
 18c:   84 09 a6 10     vslw    v5,v6,v1
 190:   10 00 e7 38     addi    r7,r7,16
 194:   10 00 a5 38     addi    r5,r5,16
 198:   40 28 63 10     vadduhm v3,v3,v5
 19c:   80 20 63 10     vadduwm v3,v3,v4
 1a0:   19 4f 66 7c     stxvw4x vs35,r6,r9
 1a4:   14 02 86 41     beq     cr1,3b8 <foo+0x3b8>
 1a8:   10 00 20 39     li      r9,16
 1ac:   19 4e 27 7d     lxvw4x  vs41,r7,r9
 1b0:   19 3e a0 7c     lxvw4x  vs37,0,r7
```

By the way, you can also get an optimization report from the XL compilers by using the [-qreport](http://vaidbld.canlab.ibm.com:10301/help/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp1311.belinux.doc/compiler_ref/opt_report.html) option.  This will explain which loops were vectorized and which loops were not and for what reason.  e.g.

> 1586-542 (I) Loop (loop index 1 with nest-level 0 and iteration count
>   100) at test.c  was SIMD vectorized.

or

> 1586-549 (I) Loop (loop index 2) at test.c  was not SIMD
>   vectorized because a data dependence  prevents SIMD vectorization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have a another question related with vectorization for-loop block when it contains function call.

Comment: Maybe you could incorporate the information about GCC from my post into yours and then I'll delete mine since it was more of an extended comment than a full answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to a Power-based machine right now, but some experimentation with the AST dumper on x86 shows that GCC 4.9.2 starts producing SIMD code only once the level of optimisation reaches `O1`, i.e. the following options should do the trick:

```
-fopenmp-simd -O1
```

The same is true for GCC 5.1.0.

Also note that the vectoriser applies a cost model that might prevent it from actually producing vectorised code in some cases. See `-fsimd-cost-model` and similar options [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) on how to override that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I compile and saw changes. But, I'm also wondering is it optimized code enough in term of altivec operations

Comment: That I don't know. But increasing the optimisation level should improve things even further.

Comment: I solved this issue. But interestingly i couldn't obtain very good results from power, for now i7 looks better. I guess it is because SSE4

Comment: Which Core i7 do you use for testing? If you use fresh one (produced after summer 2013, 4xxx or later) - then it already supports AVX2, so you can get as much as 8x speed-up theoretically (possibly even more if you deal with float instead of int, because of FMA)

Comment: @zam thank you, When I enable avx i obtain much more better result. But i haven't tried with avx since i don't have that CPU right now. is it that big difference between avx and avx2 ?

Comment: For your test case, yes, there should be big difference, because AVX2 adds two things: 1) extends SSE to AVX for integers, not just for floating point values (like AVX-1), 2) introduces "FMA==fused multiply add" (which will again affect your example in case you transfrom from integer to floats, because your test case is actually pure FMA but on integers)